# Right fibrations over $N(\Delta)$ as complete Segal spaces

Tags: localization, higher-category-theory, model-categories

Is there a Bousfield localization of the model category for right fibrations over $N(\Delta)$ that is Quillen equivalent to the model category for complete Segal spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

One can perform the left Bousfield localization with respect
to the maps [m] ⊔_[0] [n] → [m+n] and the map E → [0].

Here [m] denotes the representable fibration corresponding to the m-simplex
and ⊔ denotes the homotopy pushout of fibrations.

In the latter map the source object E encodes the free groupoid on one arrow;
it can be defined as the nerve of this groupoid,
interpreted as a simplicial object in (discrete) simplicial sets.

Locality with respect to the first class of maps ensure the Segal condition, i.e., X_{m+n} → X_m ×_{X_0} X_n is an equivalence.
Locality with respect to the second map ensures the completeness condition, i.e., X_0 → X_inv is an equivalence.

Comment: In this case, ordinary pushouts would already be homotopy pushouts (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proper+model+category#HomotopyLimits), wouldn't they? Also, could you please clarify where, in the second map, the two points are sent to? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, all maps are cofibrations with cofibrant source, hence the homotopy pushouts can be computed as pushouts.  I added a description of the second map.

Comment: I further simplified the description of the second map.